# Creating a Kubernetes cluster with Vagrant

Tags: kubernetes

I need some help in creating my first Kubernetes cluster with Vagrant. I have installed Kubernetes, Vagrant and libvirt. My kubectl status displays:

```
[root@localhost ~]# kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"0", GitVersion:"v1.0.6", GitCommit:"388061f00f0d9e4d641f9ed4971c775e1654579d", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"0", GitVersion:"v1.0.6", GitCommit:"388061f00f0d9e4d641f9ed4971c775e1654579d", GitTreeState:"clean"}
```

From the documentation I can read that the cluster can be started with:

> export KUBERNETES_PROVIDER=vagrant ./cluster/kube-up.sh

However no "cluster" folder has been created by installing kubernetes, nor the "kube-up.sh" command is available. I can see only the following ones:

```
kube-apiserver           kube-controller-manager  kubectl                  kubelet                  kube-proxy               kube-scheduler           kube-version-change
```

Am I missing some steps ? Thanks

Comment: kube-up.sh is located in the kubernetes repository, and you should have it on your machine: $KUBERNETES_ROOT/cluster/kube-up.sh, where $KUBERNETES_ROOT is where you store your copy of kubernetes. Try running `export KUBERNETES_PROVIDER=vagrant` and then go to $KUBERNETES_ROOT to run `./cluster/kube-up.sh`

Comment: When you say "I have installed Kubernetes", how did you install it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> From the documentation I can read that the cluster can be started with:
>
> export KUBERNETES_PROVIDER=vagrant ./cluster/kube-up.sh

This documentation assumes that you have downloaded a kubernetes release. You can grab the latest release ([1.1.7](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/releases/tag/v1.1.7)) from the github releases page. Once you unpack `kubernetes.tar.gz` you should see a cluster directory with `kube-up.sh` inside of it that you can execute it as suggested by the documentation.